# How to repeat a section of divs across the page using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to figure out the best way to repeat a container that holds 4 divs inside.

The container needs to span across the screen 100% leaving no white blank constantly repeating.

I dont believe this is a css issue as the divs will contain 4 images that will repeat x axis.

I would like to use jquery but cant find any code similar.?

I have created the html and css but can find any results similar to this problem. I appreciate any help !

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rAnzN/)

```
<div class="cover-photo">
        <div id="cover-wrap">
            <div id="phone-cover">
                <img src="img/assets/phone-cover.jpg" alt="phone-cover"/>
            </div>
            <div class="image-section1">
                <div class="image-wrap"><img src="img/profile-pics/disover/.jpg"></div>
                <div class="image-wrap"><img src="img/profile-pics/disover/.jpg"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="image-section2">
                <div class="image-wrap"><img src="img/profile-pics/disover/.jpg"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="image-section3">
                <div class="image-wrap"><img src="img/profile-pics/disover/.jpg"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--REPEAT THIS WRAP RIGHT-->
</div>
```

Comment: You need a templating engine, as it stands now simply duplicating that code and repeating it will have loads of repeating ID;'s

Comment: You can use this: https://github.com/codepb/jquery-template#jqueryloadtemplate